# Fill Dataframe by the elements of a list according to the rank values

Tags: python

I have a Dataframe of the rank values, for example, 1 means best, 5 means worst. The index is my samples, and the columns are the features.

Input:

> index A B C D E
>       item1      1 4 2 3 5
>   item2 2 3 4 5 1
>   item3 2 5 4 3 1
>   ......

I want to create a Dataframe to show the elements of the features according to their ranks.The columns are the rank from 1 to 5, and the contents are the features.

Output:

> index 1 2 3 4 5
>       item1      A C D B E 
>   item2 E A B C D
>   item3 E A D C B
>   ......

Comment: What format is your dataframe starting out as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `pandas`:

I'm not sure the format in which your dataframe is starting out as (csv? pandas dataframe?), but in any case, you first need to get your dataframe into pandas, looking like this:

```
>>> df
       A  B  C  D  E
index               
item1  1  4  2  3  5
item2  2  3  4  5  1
item3  2  5  4  3  1
```

Then, you can manipulate it in the way you want it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_dict = df.T.to_dict()
sorted_vals = [sorted(df_dict[i], key=df_dict[i].get) for i in df_dict.keys()]
new_df=pd.DataFrame(sorted_vals,
                    index=df.index,
                    columns=list(range(1,len(df.columns)+1)))

>>> new_df
       1  2  3  4  5
index               
item1  A  C  D  B  E
item2  E  A  B  C  D
item3  E  A  D  C  B
```

To walk you through it, the first step (`df.T.to_dict()`) creates a dictionary looking like this:

```
>>> df_dict
{'item1': {'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 2, 'D': 3, 'E': 5}, 'item2': {'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 4, 'D': 5, 'E': 1}, 'item3': {'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 4, 'D': 3, 'E': 1}}
```

From which you can sort each sub-dictionary by their value (`sorted_vals = [sorted(df_dict[i], key=df_dict[i].get) for i in df_dict.keys()]`), resulting in this:

```
>>> sorted_vals
[['A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'E'], ['E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['E', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B']]
```

The last line makes the new dataframe from that list of lists, and uses the range of 1 to n_ranks as your column names

Comment: This is exactly what I need! My data is a Dataframe.Thank you! I just have one more question, why I need  'for i in df_dict.keys()' when sorted, and why 'i for i in sorted_vals' when creating new Dataframe? Will it work faster?

Comment: Actually, you're right, you don't need `i for i in sorted_vals`. I've edited my answer. `for i in df_dict.keys()` is just to iterate over the dictionary keys, in order to sort *each subdictionary*.

Comment: You are really helpful! Thank you!